# Not able to start tomcat in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to run my spring boot app on command prompt but when I am trying tomcat is not getting started, what I am missing here? I am running the command java -jar /build/libs/name.jar .I tried eclipse IDE as well but I am getting same issue.I have also added my build.gradle in this post.

```
C:\Users\saukumar\Music\reporting-module>java -jar webapp/build/libs/reporting-webapp-0.0.1.0.jar
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/saukumar/Music/reporting-module/webapp/build/libs/reporting-webapp-0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/saukumar/Music/reporting-module/webapp/build/libs/reporting-webapp-0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
11:38:02,445 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
11:38:02,446 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
11:38:02,447 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/C:/Users/saukumar/Music/reporting-module/webapp/build/libs/reporting-webapp-0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/logback.xml]
11:38:02,487 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@1698c449 - URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/saukumar/Music/reporting-module/webapp/build/libs/reporting-webapp-0.0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/logback.xml] is not of type file
11:38:02,680 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
11:38:02,681 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
11:38:02,691 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [consoleAppender]
11:38:02,752 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[consoleAppender] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
11:38:02,752 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[consoleAppender] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
11:38:02,752 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[consoleAppender] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
11:38:02,753 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
11:38:02,758 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [dailyRollingFileAppender]
11:38:02,770 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@99550389 - No compression will be used
11:38:02,772 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@99550389 - Will use the pattern /opt/harmony/reporting-webapp/logs/reporting-webapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
11:38:02,778 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/opt/harmony/reporting-webapp/logs/reporting-webapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
11:38:02,778 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
11:38:02,784 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Thu Apr 04 11:31:19 IST 2019
11:38:02,785 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
11:38:02,789 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[dailyRollingFileAppender] - Active log file name: /opt/harmony/reporting-webapp/logs/reporting-webapp.log
11:38:02,789 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[dailyRollingFileAppender] - File property is set to [/opt/harmony/reporting-webapp/logs/reporting-webapp.log]
11:38:02,792 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.springframework] to false
11:38:02,792 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.springframework level set to DEBUG
11:38:02,792 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [dailyRollingFileAppender] to Logger[org.springframework]
11:38:02,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.epsilon.harmony.reporting] to false
11:38:02,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - com.epsilon.harmony.reporting level set to DEBUG
11:38:02,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [consoleAppender] to Logger[com.epsilon.harmony.reporting]
11:38:02,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [dailyRollingFileAppender] to Logger[com.epsilon.harmony.reporting]
11:38:02,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to INFO
11:38:02,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [consoleAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
11:38:02,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [dailyRollingFileAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
11:38:02,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:38:02,794 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5f4da5c3 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
11:38:03.499 [main] INFO  c.e.harmony.reporting.Application - Starting Application on IN-LT71919 with PID 15364 (C:\Users\saukumar\Music\reporting-module\webapp\build\libs\reporting-webapp-0.0.1.0.jar started by saukumar in C:\Users\saukumar\Music\reporting-module)
11:38:03.500 [main] DEBUG c.e.harmony.reporting.Application - Running with Spring Boot v2.0.2.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.6.RELEASE
11:38:03.502 [main] INFO  c.e.harmony.reporting.Application - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
11:38:09.475 [main] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8086"]
11:38:09.494 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
11:38:09.495 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
11:38:09.519 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.c.core.AprLifecycleListener - The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\app\client\roskumar\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;c:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Users\saukumar\Desktop\kafka\zookeeper-3.4.7.tar\zookeeper-3.4.7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\saukumar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\saukumar\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\saukumar\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\saukumar\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\saukumar\Desktop\Hadoop\spark\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin;C:\java\bin;C:\Users\saukumar\Music\gradle\gradle-4.9-bin\gradle-4.9\bin;C:\Users\saukumar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\saukumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli;.]
11:38:09.684 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
11:38:10.904 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

build.gradle

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
buildscript {
    ext { springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE' }

    dependencies { 
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:2.14.1")
        classpath("com.eriwen:gradle-css-plugin:2.14.0")
        classpath("com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.13")
        classpath("com.moowork.gradle:gradle-grunt-plugin:0.13")
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.eriwen.gradle.js'
apply plugin: 'com.eriwen.gradle.css'
apply plugin: 'com.moowork.node'
apply plugin: 'com.moowork.grunt'

node {
    version = '5.4.1'                               // Version of node to use.
    npmVersion = '3.3.12'                           // Version of npm to use.
    distBaseUrl = 'https://nodejs.org/dist'         // Base URL for fetching node distributions (change if you have a mirror).
    download = true                                 // If true, it will download node using above parameters.
                                                    // If false, it will try to use globally installed node.
    workDir = file("${project.projectDir}/nodejs")  // Set the work directory for unpacking node
    nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}")  // Set the work directory where node_modules should be located
}

grunt {
    workDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
    colors = true
    bufferOutput = false
}


version = release + '.' + build
springBoot {
    // to generate a file
    // build/resources/main/META-INF/build-info.properties
    // that is picked up by Spring Boot to display
    // via /info endpoint.
        buildInfo {
            properties {
                additional = [
                by: System.properties['user.name'],
                operatingSystem: "${System.properties['os.name']} (${System.properties['os.version']})",
                continuousIntegration: System.getenv('CI') ? true: false,
                machine: InetAddress.localHost.hostName,
                // Override buildInfo property time
                time: buildTime(),
                // Override name property
                name: 'Harmony Reporting WebApp'
                ]
            }
        }
}

def buildTime() {
    final dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")
    dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone('CST')
    dateFormat.format(new Date())
}


jar {
    baseName = 'reporting-webapp'
    version = release + '.' + build
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
configurations {
    jruby
    all*.exclude module: 'servlet-api'  
}

repositories { 


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile project(':reporting-service-lib')

    compile('org.json:json:20180813')

    compile(group: 'com.epsilon', name: 'cassandraDataStore', version: '1.0.0.58') {
       exclude group: 'com.datastax.cassandra'
    }

    compile(group: 'com.datastax.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-driver-core', version: '2.1.8')

    compile(group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version:'3.13')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
       exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module:'android-json'
    }

    testCompile('org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0') {
       exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module:'android-json'
    }
    testCompile('io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.1.0')
    testCompile('io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:3.1.0')

    jruby('org.jruby:jruby-complete:9.2.5.0')
}

processResources {
    filesMatching('application.properties') {
        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: project.version])
    }

    dependsOn 'exeCompass'
    dependsOn 'copyCss'
    dependsOn 'grunt'
    dependsOn 'individualMinify'
    dependsOn 'individualCssMinify'

    exclude '**/assets/**/*.js'
    exclude '**/assets/css/**/*.css'
    exclude '**/.sass-cache/*'

    from ("src/main/resources/static/reporting/assets"){
        include '**/*.js'
        exclude '**/vendor/*'
        into 'static/reporting/assets'
        rename { String fileName -> fileName.replace('js', 'source.js') }
    }

    from ("build/tmp/assets"){
        include '**/*.js'
        include '**/*.json'
        into 'static/reporting/assets'
    }

    from ("build/tmp/assets/css"){
        include '**/*.css'
        into 'static/reporting/assets/css'
    }

    from ("build/tmp/combine/vendor"){
        include '**/*.js'
        into 'static/reporting/assets/js/vendor'
    }

    from ("build/tmp/combine"){
        include 'vendor.js'
        include 'app1.js'
        into 'static/reporting/assets/js'
    }
}

task zip(type: Zip , dependsOn: jar) {
    fileMode = 0755
    into('config'){ from("$buildDir/resources/main") }
    into('libs') {
        from configurations.runtime
        from("$buildDir/libs/")
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives zip
}


}
```

Comment: can you show your spring boot starter file? chances are you may be missing the starter annotation.

Comment: Your application is starting, but it is stopping again immediately.

Comment: Please set the log level to DEBUG then post the Tomcat's log again.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is here:

```
11:38:09.519 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.c.core.AprLifecycleListener - The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:.....
```

More information is needed...please post your pom or gradle file with your dependencies
It seams like a misconfiguration in your tomcat.

Comment: Added build.gradle